# Aitoff projection, Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot my data with the Aitoff Projection using `matplotlib`

An example is [here](http://www.google.de/imgres?um=1&hl=en&safe=off&client=ubuntu&sa=N&channel=fs&biw=1276&bih=858&tbm=isch&tbnid=tqfN4bH9sfB6SM%3a&imgrefurl=http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/geo_demo.html&docid=5gQzolqaUnPcTM&imgurl=http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/geo_demo.hires.png&w=1100&h=900&ei=8Y9lUebaN4fWsgaNoIDIAQ&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=408&page=1&tbnh=148&tbnw=173&start=0&ndsp=29&ved=1t:429,r:4,s:0,i:97&tx=126&ty=35), but I would like to set xaxis limit and visualize only a portion of the sphere. For instance, what should I use to visualize only latitude between 0 and 90 degrees and longitudes between -90 and 90 degrees?

Comment: ok, so what have you tried? Did you try just using `set_xlim` and `set_ylim`?

Comment: yes, I have tried using `xlim(radians(0),radians(90))` but it didn't do anything do the plot.

Comment: you should edit your question to show what you tried (along with how to set the figure up etc).

Answer (score 3):

The Aitoff projection in matplotlib cannot have its limits changed - they are fixed to a global extent (I think it is because it simplifies axis creation).

Of the other tools available to you, neither Basemap nor Cartopy support the Aitoff projection.

Because its fairly easy to do, I just created an Aitoff projection definition in Cartopy, but things did not work smoothly as proj.4 has not got the inverse Aitoff definition.

I'm afraid that, for now, there doesn't appear to be a good solution to this. I'll continue to look at the possibility of doing this with Cartopy, and let you know if I find anything.

HTH